# Handlebars: transfer information from a page to another page via href

Tags: handlebars.js, partial

Let's say in Handlebars we have this `cards-list.html` partial:

```
{{#each data}}

<article class="card card_list-view card_list-view--regular">
<picture class="card-image">
    <img src="{{root}}/assets/img/{{this.img}}" alt="">
</picture>
<section class="card-section">
    <header>
        <h3><a href="{{this.url}}">{{this.title}}</a></h3>
    </header>
</section>
</article>

{{/each}}
```

Data are like this:

```
{"id": "1", 
 "title": "A",
 "img": "imga.jpg",
 "url": "card-single.html"
},
{"id": "2", 
 "title": "B",
 "img": "imgb.jpg",
 "url": "card-single.html"
}
```

And -  in `card-single.html` - I would like to render the single card simply with:

```
<article class="card card_single-view">
  <h4>{{title}}</h4}
  [etc..]
```

How can I pass, via `href` attribute or in another way, the original context of `cards-list.html` partial to `card-single.html`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After creating a partial with `Handlebars.registerPartial` you can include it in a template like so:

```
{{> cardSingle }}
```

This syntax also accepts an object parameter:

```
{{> cardSingle objectOfThings }}
```

So in your `cards-list.html` you could have something like:

```
{{#each data}}
    {{> cardSingle this }}
{{/each}}
```

And your `cardSingle` partial could use the properties of `this` directly:

```
<h4>{{title}}</h4>
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. "card-single.html" - as you can see from data - is the "view" to which you access via the href link, so it is not a child of the parent view and you can't pass the context via object parameter...

Comment: @AmintaCode Perhaps. Are you trying to transfer information from page to page? I think we're having a hard time understanding.

Comment: exactly, I would to transfer information from page to page, now I'll edit the question title...

Comment: Handlebars is made to place JS data into HTML templates, period, so there's not a "Handlebarsy" way to do this like I think you're wanting. You'll need to create a way to (1) Send data through your link, (2) receive the data in JS on the other side, then (3) Plug it into Handlebars. Explaining how to do that completely is [outside the scope of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but as a hint, you'll probably want to send your data through the link over GET query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you have the partial `cards-list.html` which you need to include inside your `card-single.html`. For which, you need to first register your partial (`cards-list` in the below example) using `Handlebars.registerPartial`.

The challenge here is, as your partial is in a separate file, you need run your application in a server (to allow Cross origin) and use the jQuery `get` function to access it and then register the partial.

I have created a 'main.js' file for the same.

## main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var template = Handlebars.compile($("#base-template").html());
  $.get('cards-list.html').done(function(text) { //Accessing cards-list.html
    Handlebars.registerPartial('cards-list', text); //Registering the partial in the name of `cards-list`
    /* Setting the JSON data here*/
    var context = {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "title": "A",
          "img": "imga.jpg",
          "url": "card-single.html"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "title": "B",
          "img": "imgb.jpg",
          "url": "card-single.html"
        }
      ]
    };
    $('#results').html(template(context)); //Rendering the result in the webpage
  });
});
```

And my 'card-single.html' looks like this.

## card-single.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- Includes jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js"></script> <!-- Includes Handlebars.js -->
  <script src="main.js"></script> <!-- Includes main.js -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="results">
    <script id="base-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <article class="card card_single-view">
        <h4>{{title}}</h4> <!-- This won't print anything unless in an each loop or use {{data.[0].title}} instead-->
        {{> cards-list}} <!-- Calling the partial -->
      </article>
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the 'cards-list.html' provided by you.

## cards-list.html

```
{{#each data}}
  <article class="card card_list-view card_list-view--regular">
  <picture class="card-image">
      <img src="{{root}}/assets/img/{{this.img}}" alt="">
  </picture>
  <section class="card-section">
      <header>
          <h3><a href="{{this.url}}">{{this.title}}</a></h3>
      </header>
  </section>
  </article>
{{/each}}
```

All these 3 files are in the same directory and as I'm using a mac, I just need to navigate to the directory and run the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` to start the server. (For windows we may use an apache tomcat server).

After which, simply access the file in a browser with the url `http://0.0.0.0:8000/card-single.html`.

[GITHUB link](https://github.com/gibinealias/handlebars-partials). Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. "card-single.html" - as you can see from data - is the "single view" to which you access via the href link and in which you can view only the data of a single card - not the cards list loop....

Comment: Could you please specify how your desired output would look like?